# Error "UNIQUE constraint failed" with composite primary key

Tags: trigger, primary-key, unique-constraint, sqlite3

With littele SQL(ite) practice, I tried to create a table with a composite primary key:

```sqlite3
CREATE TABLE NAMES (
  TYPE INTEGER NOT NULL,
  SEQ INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (TYPE, SEQ)
);
```

The idea is to store associations from numbers to names, i.e.: `SEQ` to `NAME` and back.
As there is a variable number of such "classes" I added a `TYPE` column, that is that the `SEQ` numbers (and `NAME`s) should be *unique within a specific `TYPE`*.

I also tried to create a trigger that will automatically assign the "next free" `SEQ` number within a specific `TYPE` like this:

```sqlite3
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_NAMES_ADD AFTER INSERT ON NAMES
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE NAMES SET SEQ = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM NAMES WHERE TYPE = NEW.TYPE)
    WHERE TYPE = NEW.TYPE;
END;
```

When I insert the first entry, it seems to work, but when I try to add a second one, it fails with

> Runtime error: UNIQUE constraint failed: NAMES.TYPE, NAMES.SEQ (19)

like this:

```sqlite3
sqlite> select * from NAMES;
sqlite> insert into NAMES (type, seq, name) values (0, -1, "test");             sqlite> select * from NAMES;
0|1|test
sqlite> insert into NAMES (type, seq, name) values (0, -1, "test2");
Runtime error: UNIQUE constraint failed: NAMES.TYPE, NAMES.SEQ (19)
sqlite> insert into NAMES (type, seq, name) values (1, -1, "test2");
sqlite> select * from NAMES;
0|1|test
1|1|test2
```

So the trigger seems to work for each `TYPE` exactly once, but maybe it's not working, because the first `SEQ` should have been 0 instead of 1.

I had also tried a `BEFORE` rather than `AFTER` trigger, but that would not change `SEQ` t all (using -1).

What's wrong with the trigger, or is it the table definition?

Comment: You use AFTER INSERT trigger. It will fire after the row is saved. But it cannot be saved because of the value duplication. Use BEFORE INSERT trigger and set `NEW.SEQ` to new needed value, not UPDATE.

Comment: Would you suggest the correct trigger as an answer? I'm fighting with the correct syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the non-unique `WHERE` clause missing `AND SEQ = NEW.SEQ` in the trigger.
This version of the trigger works correctly:

```sqlite3
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_NAMES_ADD AFTER INSERT ON NAMES
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE NAMES SET
        SEQ = (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(SEQ), 0) + 1 FROM NAMES WHERE TYPE = NEW.TYPE)
    WHERE TYPE = NEW.TYPE AND SEQ = NEW.SEQ;
END;
```

Comment: A bit of warning, if for one reason or another an old seq row is deleted you will get a conflict. You may consider using : `... = (SELECT MAX(SEQ)+1 FROM NAMES WHERE ...` instead. I don't know SQLLITE, but chances are that it is faster to locate the "last" row instead of counting

Comment: Actually I had realized that (I was copying from another trigger without thinking too much), and I fixed it, so I'll update the answer.